# Image overlay on hover?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the classic "black" overlay on hover of an image. For some reason mine is white. Can anyone explain to me what i'm doing wrong? Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncage/avwscmkq/).

```
<img class="thumb-img">

.thumb-img:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    background-color: #202020;
}
```

Comment: Your code says "when I hover on this image, make it 50% opacity/transparent" and it's on a white background so it gives the impression of having a white overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `background-color` property is never seen, since the image itself occupies the entire space of the element. Wrap it in a `<div>` (or similar):

```css
.img-fade {
    background-color: #202020;
    float:left;
}
.img-fade img {
     display: block;
  
     -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
         -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
          -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
             transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.img-fade img:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-fade">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />  
</div>
```

Comment: Good call on this having the "overlay" be the background instead? I've been a duncecap and adding an absolutely positioned overlay and using jQuery to add a hover state. But in that case it was called for since there was content on the overlay that needed to be 100% opacity.

Comment: @Benm thanks i appreciate the help. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @coding4fun No problem!